# Does pdo escape statements or not?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have this PDO wrapper

```
private function cleanup($bind) {
    if(!is_array($bind)) {
        if(!empty($bind))
            $bind = array($bind);
        else
            $bind = array();
    }
    return $bind;
}

public function run($sql, $bind="") {
    $this->sql = trim($sql);
    $this->bind = $this->cleanup($bind);
    $this->error = "";
    array_push($this->qs, $sql);

    try {
        $pdostmt = $this->prepare($this->sql);
        if($pdostmt->execute($this->bind) !== false) {
            if(preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("select", "describe", "pragma")) . ") /i", $this->sql))
                return $pdostmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            elseif(preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("delete", "insert", "update")) . ") /i", $this->sql))
                return $pdostmt->rowCount();
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        $this->debug();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I had no problems with this since I started using it a couple of years back and now I'm getting an error message because a string is not escaped. Maybe I never worked with a scenario like this.

Here's the SQL statement that is causing the problem

```
$db->run("SELECT region_id FROM region WHERE name = '$name'");
```

where `$name` is Hawke's Bay. I was under the impression that PDO escapes strings, seems like I was wrong. Any ideas how I can fix this issue?

Comment: If you are not using PDO::prepare, you need to manually escape strings using PDO::quote.

Comment: @DevlshOne `$pdostmt = $this->prepare($this->sql);` there's the prepare

Comment: @slash197 Have you read the code at least? There is nothing to prepare in the statement

Comment: @YourCommonSense ok, then what does that 'prepare' do then? Or what did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you by chance come across a thing called "placeholder"?

Comment: I did look at your code and it looks like you're `bind`ing before you `prepare`. I thought I read that this somehow messes with the `prepare` method? Maybe I'm mistaken. That's why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense something like `:name`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. the thing that makes your query a prepared statement

Comment: @YourCommonSense So `$db->run("SELECT region_id FROM region WHERE name = ':name'", array(':name' => $name));` would make this query prepared?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354412/prepared-statements-escape-variables

Comment: Nope. this one wouldn't. You need to use correct syntax explained in the manual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 false assumptions that led you to this question

1. Escaping is a thing that makes your query correct one.
2. PDO does this "escaping" whatever "magic" way, knowing somehow what to escape.

Unfortunately, both assumptions are wrong.

As a matter of fact, escaping required **for the SQL strings only**. It has nothing to do with PDO, prepared statements, safety and such. Once you are going to put a string literal into query - it must have special characters escaped.
But once you aren't - no escaping would be good.

Regarding PDO, you want it not to "escape" but to process **placeholders** in your query. This is how the whole thing works. 
Using placeholders you are telling PDO to **format** corresponding values properly. While such a formatting involves not just escaping but many more different measures.

So, it have to be something like this

```
$db->run("SELECT region_id FROM region WHERE name = :name", array(':name' => $name));
```

this way PDO will treat $name as a string and format it accordingly.

Though I am not sure about "cleanup" function if it works properly and why it is used at all.

Answer (score 0):

By default not PDO doesn't quote anything if you use plain query instead of prepared statements. But you can use `PDO::quote()` method for escaping individual values. See more http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: You shouldn't use this function but prepared statements.

Comment: This is not an arguement for me.