# MySQLi prepared statement fails and won't be executed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm having a problem with my SQL statement, it gives the error on the first if statement, the SQL statement has been failed. For prepared statements I've used mmtuts and w3schools, but I don't know what's going wrong.

Here's my code:

```
function login($conn) {
  if (isset($_POST['submitLogin'])) {
    $username = $conn->escape_string($_POST['emailorusername']);
    $password = $conn->escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      header("Location: ?error=sqlstatementfailed");
      exit();
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        header("Location: ?username=notfound");
        exit();
      } else {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1) {
          header("Location: ?error=toomuchresults");
          exit();
        } else {
          header("Location: ?username=ok");
          if ($password !== $row['password']) {
            header("Location: ?password=false");
            exit();
          } else {
            header("Location: ?password=ok");
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
            $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
            header("Location: Index");
            exit();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The server is connected to the database so that isn't the problem.

Can someone help? Thanks!

**Solution:**

Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after your prepare, it will tell you why it failed.

Comment: Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after your prepare, it will tell you why it failed.

Comment: Also, why are you preparing it twice?

Comment: Thank you, I was stupid and forgot some columns. The next time I'll use this again!

Oh yes I see that I'm preparing it twice, I'll remove it!

Comment: Please read up how to use [`password_hash()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash)

Comment: You shouldn't have to escape a string if you're binding it as a parameter. That can actually cause problems.

Comment: @NigelRen ? Where am I using it?

Comment: @Don'tPanic ok, but what kind of problem can you get?

Comment: @J0eppp If any characters are actually escaped, the escape characters will be stored with your data. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34692482/2734189) for a good explanation.

Comment: @Don'tPanic ok, thank you! 

BTW: Can someone tell me how I can "complete" this question? It's fixed so yeah...

Comment: @J0eppp as far as "completing" a question, there are a few different ways. If someone answers, and their answer solves your problem, you can accept the answer. If you solved the problem yourself, then you can either add an answer that explains how you did it, or if you don't think that would be useful to others, you can delete the question. But you don't really need to worry about it. It's okay for Qs to remain open. Really, even after you have accepted an answer other people can still add new answers.

Comment: However, if you see a pattern developing of never getting an answer you can accept, you should take a close look at how you write your questions. There are a lot of resources available that offer guidance in writing good questions. It's more difficult than most people think it is.

Comment: Thanks, I've experienced already that it's pretty hard to ask something. Thanks for your help guys!